# Prefix a string with a character based on a condition

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame which contains a variable "RingNo"

```
> head(leg)
  Place Book.Number RingNo
1   WYT     2020#01 603701
2   WYT     2020#01 603701
3   WYT     2020#01 603701
4   WYT     2020#01 603702
5   WYT     2020#01 603703
6   WYT     2020#01 A394567
```

What I am trying to do is add an "x" to the beginning of any string in `leg$RingNo` which has only 6 characters
I have tried using `stri_sub` in the `stringi` package which I can use to add the "x" to all the strings in `leg$RingNo` but I'm struggling to find a way to do it based on the condition stated above.

This is ideally how it would look

```
> head(leg)
  Place Book.Number RingNo
1   WYT     2020#01 x603701
2   WYT     2020#01 x603701
3   WYT     2020#01 x603701
4   WYT     2020#01 x603702
5   WYT     2020#01 x603703
6   WYT     2020#01 A394567
```

All solutions welcome and thanks in advance

Comment: Is the goal to pad all >7 character strings to 7 characters with `x`, or specifically to act only on 6 character strings? For former stringi does have a baked in solution: `stringi::stri_pad_left("2020", width = 7, pad = "x")`.

Comment: Just to work on the 6 character strings, but that is also a nice solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nchar` to count number of characters and then use `paste0` to add prefix.

```
inds <- nchar(df$RingNo) == 6
df$RingNo[inds] <- paste0('x', df$RingNo[inds])
df

#  Place Book.Number  RingNo
#1   WYT     2020#01 x603701
#2   WYT     2020#01 x603701
#3   WYT     2020#01 x603701
#4   WYT     2020#01 x603702
#5   WYT     2020#01 x603703
#6   WYT     2020#01 A394567
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(RingNo = case_when(nchar(RingNo) == 6 
          ~ str_c('x', RingNo), TRUE ~ RingNo))
```